# Allow inbound SSH traffic to EC2 with boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, boto3

I was able to authorize ingress traffic via awscli, but struggling to do so with boto3. Calling this function succeeds, and launches an instance with a public IP, but ssh traffic seems rejected. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

My usecase is just run some heavy compute workload one time on one instance of EC2, so I don't particularly need to set up fully-fledged custom routing / bastion hosts etc.

```py
import boto3

def create_security_group_and_launch_instance(region, availability_zone, vpc_id, subnet_id, name = 'mytest', instance_type = 't2.micro', image_name = 'ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210430'):
  ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = region)

  security_group = ec2.create_security_group(GroupName = name, Description = name, VpcId = vpc_id)

  ec2.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId = security_group['GroupId'], IpProtocol = 'tcp', FromPort = 22, ToPort = 22, CidrIp = '0.0.0.0/0')

  images = ec2.describe_images(Filters = [dict(Name = 'name', Values = [image_name])])
  image_id = images['Images'][0]['ImageId']

  cold_instance_run = ec2.run_instances(
        InstanceType = instance_type,
        ImageId = image_id,
        MinCount = 1,
        MaxCount = 1,
        KeyName = name,
        Placement = dict(AvailabilityZone = availability_zone),
        NetworkInterfaces = [dict(DeviceIndex = 0, Groups = [security_group['GroupId']], SubnetId = subnet_id, AssociatePublicIpAddress = True)]
    )
```

Comment: After the instance is launched, take a look at the Security Group. Is it configured how you want? Also make sure it is creating an Outbound set of rules (not required for SSH, but any software installs would need it). And what do you mean by "ssh traffic seems rejected" -- what error message do you get if you connect with `ssh -vvv ...`?

Comment: It just says `port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable`, and `-vvv` doesn't give any more information. I'll check the security group, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sounds like something wrong at the Operating System-level: https://superuser.com/questions/1098526/windows-10-linux-subsystem-ssh-client-resource-temporarily-unavailable

Comment: I don't think so, ssh to other machines works well. And when I used awscli before, it also worked fine.

Comment: The problem seems to be that my subnet doesn't have an internet gateway in its route table. How do I configure the subnet to have an internet gateway / route?

Comment: Indeed, this is the problem. In EC2 Console I manually created an Internet Gateway, associated it with VPC and then added a route to my subnet's Route Table. Then ssh works. I'll try to figure out the boto3 method call sequence. It should be something along the lines of https://gist.github.com/nguyendv/8cfd92fc8ed32ebb78e366f44c2daea6, but updated to more recent boto3.